# Navbar collapse does not work in Tablet View

Tags: html, css, navbar, transition, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a navbar that does collapse as it should in mobile view but on the tablet (or ipad pro) there is a break or large padding/gap that breaks the navigation. The testing site is at:

[padding or margin bottom occurs in tablet view](http://patskailua.com/div6.html)

I have tried a number of things like adjusting the viewport and adding links to bootstraps transition.js and collapse.js files but that is not working either.

```
<!--navigation bar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default transparent navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="navbar-main">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://patskailua.com/index.php"><img src="http://patskailua.com/images/kailua-beach-properties-llc.png"  alt="pats kailua hawaiian Flower" usemap="#Map" class="img-responsive">
</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="navbar-header">
<div class="text-center">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navCollapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span> Menu
</button>    
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navCollapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="active goleft1"><a href="http://patskailua.com/wp/our-vacation-properties.php">vacation rentals</a></li>
<li><a href="http://patskailua.com/wp/sightseeing.php">kailua activities</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">rentals by size<span class="caret black"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="http://patskailua.com/wp/three-bedrooms.php" >Three Bedrooms</a></li>
<li><a href="http://patskailua.com/wp/two-bedrooms.php">Two Bedrooms</a></li>
<li><a href="http://patskailua.com/wp/one-bedrooms.php">One Bedrooms</a></li>
<li><a href="http://patskailua.com/wp/studios.php">Studios</a></li>
</ul>
</li><li><a href="http://patskailua.com/wp/contact-us.php">contact us</a>            </li>
<li><a href=" http://patskailua.com/wp/about-us.php">about us</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href=" http://patskailua.com/wp/property-management.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">property management and sales<span class="caret black"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href=" http://patskailua.com/wp/property-management.php">Property Management</a></li>
<li><a href=" http://patskailua.com/wp/buying-a-home-in-hawaii.php">Buying a Property</a></li>
<li><a href=" http://patskailua.com/wp/selling-a-home-in-hawaii.php">Selling a Property</a></li>

     <li class="goleft"><a href="http://patskailua.com/index.php">home</a></li>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</nav>
<!--end nav bar-->
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, that would be great. Thanks so much. -Beth

Comment: please post your code or recreate in a minimal and complete example

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the class `col-lg-12` by `col-md-12` or even `col-sm-12`.

This should make your navbar adapt better smaller resolutions.

Comment: I am wondering if adding a max height to the navbar might work?